# ADFS 2.0 Single Sign Out Not Signing Out

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0

I'm having an issue with a web application I'm writing that implements ADFS 2.0. I am able to get users to sign in just fine, but I do have situations where the user needs to be able to sign out of the application to allow other users to sign in.

What happens is when the user clicks the sign out button it runs through the following method:

```
    public void SignOut()
    {
        WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.ADFSIssuer),
            new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.ADFSRealm));
    }
```

My ADFS Issuer is the https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/ls/ piece, and my ADFS Realm is the main url of my web application.

The application appears to have then signed out. When another user clicks the Login button, it automatically signs them in as the previous user without prompting for credentials.

I've looked at the following resources for assistance and nothing has worked:

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/195
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx

Am I not supposed to be able to signout of an ADFS application without closing the browser?

Comment: Can you check which cookies exist when not yet logged-in, when logged-in and after you sign-out. Notice the domains of the cookies.

Comment: I cleared my cache before logging in. I have no cookies before logging in, after logging in I have a number of cookies assigned to me by ADFS, and then two cookies by my actual web application. After logging out I have two cookies still assigned to me by ADFS: MSISIPSelectionPersistent and MSISLoopDetectionCookie.

Comment: What authentication mode (forms or windows) your adfs is configured to?

Comment: That is probably the reason why the new user gets the previous credentials. The RP or STS assumes it already authenticated because it still sees these cookies.

Comment: @Wiktor: The authentication mode ADFS is configured to is Windows.

Comment: Is the client pc domain joined?

Comment: @Rene: Can I just add two new HTTP Cookies with the same names as those two that expire a day before in an effort to remove them?

Comment: Bingo, see my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't ADFSRealm point to a LogOut method on your website? You can only set those cookies if they are owned by your website. You can check if the domains match

Comment: @rene: it doesn't matter, wreply param only points to a site adfs redirects to. It has nothing to do with cookies.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I was unsure about that part, tnx for clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am only guessing but I suspect that your adfs is configurd for windows authentication while your application has the Login button (it is not clear from your description).

If this is the case then you can't really log out from already authenticated adfs and it happily reissues the token upon the next request from the application. You can't do anything about it since the authentication is performed with ntlm/kerberos and this is the browser that keeps your credentials until you close it.

The solution would be to change adfs to Forms mode (switch the order of providers in adfs web.config) so that not only the adfs has its own cookies but also these cookies are truly removed when you issue the sign out message.

Comment: Would changing ADFS to forms mode prevent the automatic sign in of the current windows user?

Comment: Yes it would. You can't have both.

Comment: so you can either have automatic sign in, or the ability to sign out, but not both?